# Не работает авторизация по приватному ключу в командной строке через putty

Tags: windows, git, putty

В Git Extensions получение коммитов с сервера (pull) работает с настроенным приватным ключом, но при попытке запустить через командную строку (или Far Manager) просит пароль.

Почему настройки PuTTY не срабатывают?

Мои настройки Git Extensions:
[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH клиент задается не через конфиг-файл, а через переменную окружения GIT_SSH. Git Extensions не умеет изменять настройки переменных окружения пользователя, поэтому применяет их только для своих дочерних процессов. Поэтому в при запуске через командную строку git использует стандартный OpenSSH вместо настроенного PuTTY.

Задайте переменную окружения `GIT_SSH=C:\путь\к\GitExtensions\PuTTY\plink.exe` для своего пользователя в настройках Windows.

Это делается через "Панель управления" - "Система" - "Дополнительные параметры системы" (на XP этот шаг пропускается) - "Переменные среды".